# Replace div it when window is smaller with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one with a text phone number and one with a phone button graphic. I want the larger number to disappear and be replaced with the smaller graphic when the window size is smaller. I have three style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 620px)" href="mobile0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 840px)" href="mobile1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 840px)" href="mobile2.css">
```

`mobile2.css` is for large displays, `mobile1.css` is for tablets, and `mobile0.css` is for phones.

Since `mobile2.css` and `mobile1.css` are the same for this, I will show `mobile2.css` and `mobile0`.

The divs in `mobile2.css`:

```
.phone_remove {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 220%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #407595;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.phone_button {
    display: none;
}
```

The divs in `mobile0.css`:

```
.phone_remove {
    display: none;
}

.phone_button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The phone number disappears as expected, but the phone button does not appear.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="phone_button"><a href="tel:760-471-1700">
    <img src="images/phone_us.jpg" width="100%" border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="phone_remove">760.471.1700</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with block, instead of inline-block?

Comment: Have you tried css media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries